# Send file to API with PHP using cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to upload a file to this API : http://www.noelshack.com/api.php
I don't know anything about cURL. I have find sample codes, and i have try this :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.noelshack.com/api.php');

// send a file
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $curl,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'fichier' => '@http://cdn.soccerwiki.org/images/player/2386.jpg'
    ));

// output the response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($result);

curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Can anyone explain me with my current code don't work ?
It should return a url like this : http://www.noelshack.com/2016-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-2386.png

But it didn't return anything. There aren't any error in my code, the file is juste not uploaded, and i don't know why because i don't know how to display api errors !

Thanks in advance

(sorry for my english, i'm french)

Comment: i have add this code to see if curl return an error :

if(curl_exec($curl) === false) { echo 'curl error : '.curl_error($curl); } else {
echo "no problem"; }

and it returns "no problem" !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 potential issues.

1. To POST a file using cURL, it must be located on the local filesystem.  You can't specify a file over `http://`.
2. Depending on your PHP version you may need to use the [`CURLFile`](http://php.net/curlfile) class instead of prepending the filename with an `@`.

Here is some code that fixes both issues:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.noelshack.com/api.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0');
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.noelshack.com/api.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

// download image to temp file for upload
$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'php');
file_put_contents($tmp, file_get_contents('http://cdn.soccerwiki.org/images/player/2386.jpg'));

// send a file
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $curl,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'fichier' => new CURLFile($tmp),
      'submit'  => 'Envoyer',
    ));

// output the response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($result, curl_error($curl));

unlink($tmp); // remove temp file

curl_close($curl);
```

If you don't have PHP 5.5.0 or greater, just remove the `CURLFile` construction and replace it with `'@' . $tmp,`

Comment: Hi @drew010 I am working with php 7.1.1 and trying to upload image with CURL. But not succeed
here is my code
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'someurl');
$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$filedata = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$filetype = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$cFile = new CURLFile($filedata, $filetype, 'harish');
$data = array('upload-file' => $cFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $sheader);
curl_exec($ch);
?>